# Can one object be initialized in the main thread and have its methods executed in a separate thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading

I have an object which I initialize in the app's main thread but I call one of its methods in a background thread using `performSelectorInBakground`. However, the method seems to be unresponsive. More specifically :

AccHandler.m

```
#import "AccHandler.h"

@implementation AccHandler
@synthesize accelerationOnYaxis;
-(void)startAccelerationUpdates
{
    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01; 
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                                       withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
     {
         self.accelerationOnYaxis = motion.userAcceleration.y;
     }
     ];
}
@end
```

Tester.m

```
#import "Tester.h"

@interface Tester()
{
   AccHandler *accHandler;
}
@end

@implementation Tester
- (id) init
{
    //....
    accHandler = [[AccHandler alloc] init]; // initialized in main thread
}

-(void)test
{
    [accHandler startAccelerationUpdates]; // but -(void)test will be executed in a background thread..
    NSLog(@"current acceleration is %f", accHandler.accelerationOnYaxis;
}
```

later on in my code I call the `test` method from a `performSelectorInBackground` but I get 0 acceleration values..

Comment: just to make sure, you know when you throw a method in another thread you need to wait for it to complete (aka using a completion handler) to get any results out of it right?

Comment: as far as I can tell, `-test` will only run once is that what you want? Also, `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:` will return immediately, but the block you pass will not run immediately--it may run some time later.

Comment: it will only run once but I have actually tested the NSLog line in a while loop just to make sure that I'm not only getting a first read which just happens to be zero. @iBlue I didn't know that and I'm not sure I know how to do that, being rather new to multithreading in general..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can one object be initialized in the main thread and have its methods
>   executed in a separate thread?

Yes.

Your mistake seems to be that you are not waiting for the background stuff to produce results.

Another problem might be that `motionManager` does not seem to be retained by some strong reference. So it might just immediately go away after initialization.

Comment: Ok I now see what I did there. I'll try to find a solution and come back to you with a bit more concrete results, thank you!